# О каком явлении идёт речь в представленном диалектном тексте?

Tags: диалектология

Стихотворение «Бугристы берега, благоприятны влаги…» М. Ломоносов написал в связи со спорами о целесообразности введения двух особых знаков для взрывного и фрикативного «г». В отличие от Тредиаковского, Ломоносов считал достаточным в русском правописании одного знака и подобрал в своем стихотворении слова, в которых, по его мнению, трудно было определить взрывное или фрикативное «г». О каком диалектном явлении, которое сохраняется до настоящего времени в русском языке, идет речь? Как будет звучать данное стихотворение в разных типах говоров в речи жителей России (севера и юга). Какие слова в этом стихотворении могут быть написаны жителями севера и юга  с разными буквами?

[image: Стихотворение]

Comment: Даже если помощь получена, зачем удалять вопрос таким способом?!